# Duck Typing for Razor views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, duck-typing

I have a data session model which contains many different types of applicants. All of these have FirstName and LastName properties which I would like to display in a razor view.

```
var applicant = model.Lead ??
                model.Drivers.FirstOrDefault() ??
                model.Loans.FirstOrDefault() ?? 
                model.Renewals.FirstOrDefault();
```

At first glance, I would use inheritance, except that these are classes in an EF database, not sure how to setup a parent class.

Is there a clean way to do this or am I stuck with something like this?

```
dynamic applicant = new ExpandoObject();

if (model.Lead != null) {
   applicant.FirstName = model.Lead.FirstName;
   applicant.LastName = model.Lead.LastName;
} else if ( model.Drivers.Any() ) {
   var first = model.Drivers.FirstOrDefault();
   applicant.FirstName = first.FirstName;
   applicant.LastName = first.LastName;
} else if ...
```

Comment: Can your application types implement an interface with the common properties? Then you pass the interface to razor.

Comment: I don't know, can I inherit the interface in a partial?

Comment: Sure, though the partial class that inherits the interface has to have the implementation. Are you partial classes code generated from EF?

Comment: You can set the view model type to dynamic then pass in any normal object. An interface is easier and works fine with partial classes, the implementation can be in either part of the partial or split across it.

Comment: @AnishPatel Yes, the code is generated by EF (database first, edmx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an interface.

Assuming your EF code generated models look like this:

```
public partial class Driver {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // other properties ...
}

public partial class Loan {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // other properties ...
}

public partial class Renewal {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // other properties ...
}

public partial class Lead {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // other properties ...
}
```

Then create an interface that defines the common properties:

```
public interface IApplication {
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then *implement* that interface:

```
public partial class Driver : IApplication {}

public partial class Loan : IApplication {}

public partial class Renewal : IApplication {}

public partial class Lead : IApplication {}
```

Then set the model in your view to:

```
@model IEnumerable<IApplication>
```

And then you can return an IEnumerable collection filled with different concretes types and access the common properties which are defined on the interface.